# MySQL: Producer/Consumer Model, need atomicity in commands accessing multiple tables

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, stored-functions, atomic

I have the following 2 tables, with sample values:

```
producer_tbl:
id (auto-inc, PK)  producer_id   item_id   item_added
       2               5            3          20

products_available_tbl:
item_id (PK)   avail_cnt   blocked_cnt
  3               9             2
```

Here is the method how I access them:

When a manufacturer provides me with an item, I insert appropriate data in producer_tbl. I simultaneously increment the avail_cnt for the respective item in products_available_tbl.

When a consumer wants that given item, I first use (avail_cnt - blocked_cnt) to check if the quantity asked for is available. If so, I increment the blocked_cnt with the quantity, but don't update avail_cnt. When the consumer commits to his request, I decrement the blocked_cnt and avail_cnt, both with the same quantity.

Now, when there are multiple producers and consumers touching the same item simultaneously, I need atomicity for the above operations.

I would like to know if can I solve this with triggers? (I don't want to use external mutexes) Anyone can point me to sample examples of how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your [request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11593380/mysql-producer-consumer-model-need-atomicity-in-commands-accessing-multiple-ta/11697700#comment15447921_11612924), below are comments that focus on the performance issues in your code:

### Optimizing add_item()

Assuming that the `products_available_tbl` has a unique index on `item_id`, then

```
CREATE PROCEDURE add_item(IN in_producer_id INT, IN in_item_id INT,
                                                IN in_item_cnt INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE item INT DEFAULT NULL;
    START TRANSACTION;

    INSERT INTO producer_tbl (producer_id, item_id, item_cnt)
        VALUES (in_producer_id, in_item_id, in_item_cnt);

    SELECT item_id FROM products_available_tbl 
        WHERE item_id=in_item_id INTO item FOR UPDATE;

    IF item IS NOT NULL THEN
        UPDATE products_available_tbl 
            SET avail_cnt=avail_cnt + in_item_cnt
            WHERE item_id=in_item_id;
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO products_available_tbl 
            (item_id, avail_cnt, blocked_cnt)
            VALUES (in_item_id, in_item_cnt, 0);
    END IF;

    COMMIT;
END //
```

could be rewritten as:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE add_item(IN in_producer_id INT, IN in_item_id INT,
                                                IN in_item_cnt INT)
BEGIN
    START TRANSACTION;

    INSERT INTO producer_tbl (producer_id, item_id, item_cnt)
        VALUES (in_producer_id, in_item_id, in_item_cnt);

    INSERT INTO products_available_tbl SET
        item_id = in_item_id,
        avail_cnt = in_item_cnt,
        blocked_cnt = 0
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
        avail_cnt = avail_cnt + in_item_cnt;

    COMMIT;
END //
```

### Optimizing block_item()

The optimization is significant, so let's proceed in stages:

First, let's rewrite

```
SET out_cnt = var_avail_cnt - var_blocked_cnt;
IF out_cnt >= cnt THEN
    SET out_cnt = cnt;
END IF;
```

as

```
SET out_cnt = LEAST(var_avail_cnt - var_blocked_cnt, cnt);
```

Next, let's rewrite

```
SELECT avail_cnt, blocked_cnt FROM products_available_tbl
    WHERE item_id=in_item_id INTO var_avail_cnt, var_blocked_cnt
    FOR UPDATE;

SET out_cnt = LEAST(var_avail_cnt - var_blocked_cnt, cnt);
```

as

```
SELECT LEAST(avail_cnt - blocked_cnt, cnt) FROM products_available_tbl
    WHERE item_id=in_item_id INTO out_cnt
    FOR UPDATE;
```

Finally, let's rewrite

```
SELECT LEAST(avail_cnt - blocked_cnt, cnt) FROM products_available_tbl
    WHERE item_id=in_item_id INTO out_cnt
    FOR UPDATE;

UPDATE products_available_tbl
    SET blocked_cnt = var_blocked_cnt + out_cnt
    WHERE item_id = in_item_id;
```

as

```
UPDATE products_available_tbl
    SET 
    blocked_cnt = blocked_cnt + (@out_cnt := LEAST(avail_cnt - blocked_cnt, cnt))
    WHERE item_id = in_item_id;
```

so

```
CREATE PROCEDURE block_item(IN in_item_id INT, INOUT cnt INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE out_cnt INT DEFAULT cnt;
    DECLARE var_avail_cnt, var_blocked_cnt INT DEFAULT 0;
    START TRANSACTION;

    SELECT avail_cnt, blocked_cnt FROM products_available_tbl
        WHERE item_id=in_item_id INTO var_avail_cnt, var_blocked_cnt
        FOR UPDATE;

    SET out_cnt = var_avail_cnt - var_blocked_cnt;
    IF out_cnt >= cnt THEN
        SET out_cnt = cnt;
    END IF;

    UPDATE products_available_tbl
        SET blocked_cnt = var_blocked_cnt + out_cnt
        WHERE item_id = in_item_id;

    SET cnt = out_cnt;
    COMMIT;
END //
```

becomes

```
CREATE PROCEDURE block_item(IN in_item_id INT, INOUT cnt INT)
BEGIN
    UPDATE products_available_tbl
        SET 
        blocked_cnt = blocked_cnt + (@out_cnt := LEAST(avail_cnt - blocked_cnt, cnt))
        WHERE item_id = in_item_id;

    SET cnt = @out_cnt;
END //
```

### Optimizing commit_item():

Let's rewrite

```
CREATE PROCEDURE commit_item(IN in_item_id INT, INOUT cnt INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE out_cnt INT DEFAULT cnt;
    DECLARE var_avail_cnt, var_blocked_cnt INT DEFAULT 0;
    START TRANSACTION;

    SELECT avail_cnt, blocked_cnt FROM products_available_tbl
        WHERE item_id=in_item_id INTO var_avail_cnt, var_blocked_cnt
        FOR UPDATE;

    IF cnt > var_blocked_cnt THEN
        SET out_cnt = -1;  /* Error case: Caller supplied wrong value. */
    ELSEIF var_blocked_cnt > var_avail_cnt THEN
        SET out_cnt = -2;  /* Error case: Bug in block_item proc. */
    ELSE
        SET out_cnt = cnt;

        UPDATE products_available_tbl
            SET blocked_cnt = var_blocked_cnt - out_cnt,
                avail_cnt = var_avail_cnt - out_cnt
            WHERE item_id = in_item_id;
    END IF;

    SET cnt = out_cnt;
    COMMIT;
END //
```

as

```
CREATE PROCEDURE commit_item(IN in_item_id INT, INOUT cnt INT)
proc: BEGIN
    DECLARE var_avail_cnt, var_blocked_cnt INT DEFAULT 0;

    UPDATE products_available_tbl
        SET blocked_cnt   = blocked_cnt - cnt,
            avail_cnt     = avail_cnt - cnt
        WHERE item_id     = in_item_id
        AND   cnt         <= blocked_cnt
        AND   blocked_cnt <= avail_cnt;

    IF ROW_COUNT() > 0 THEN
        LEAVE proc;
    END IF;

    SELECT avail_cnt, blocked_cnt FROM products_available_tbl
        WHERE item_id=in_item_id INTO var_avail_cnt, var_blocked_cnt;

    IF cnt > var_blocked_cnt THEN
        SET cnt = -1;  /* Error case: Caller supplied wrong value. */
    ELSEIF var_blocked_cnt > var_avail_cnt THEN
        SET cnt = -2;  /* Error case: Bug in block_item proc. */
    ELSE
        SET cnt = -3; /* UPDATE failed, reasons unknown. */
    END IF;
END //
```

I hope these help. Let me know what you think!

Comment: Ross: This is fantastic! Great code, thanks for adding. There is a minor fix required in block_item. Will edit it.

Comment: Minor fix in commit_item (sql syntax)

Comment: Ethan, try this latest change, I *think* it will work for you. I you like my answer, please upvote it!

Comment: Ross: Fantastic! This is _exactly_ what I was looking for but didn't know howto. I will test it out.

Comment: Note a final (?) cleanup just now.

Answer (score 1):

You can always make sure you are updating the record you just read, by adding a `uuid VARCHAR(32)` column to any table. You read the record you want to update, then you update the record with a check that the `uuid` field didn't change.

For example, you can increment `blocked_cnt` via:

```
UPDATE products_available_tbl
   SET blocked_cnt = blocked_cnt + 1,
       uuid = UUID()
 WHERE blocked_cnt = 2
   AND uuid = '21EC2020-3AEA-1069-A2DD-08002B30309D';

SELECT ROW_COUNT(); -- a 1 indicates the UPDATE was successful, 0 or -1 failure
```

To decrement the `blocked_cnt` and `avail_cnt` fields:

```
UPDATE products_available_tbl
   SET blocked_cnt = blocked_cnt - 1,
       avail_cnt = avail_cnt - 1,
       uuid = UUID()
 WHERE blocked_cnt = 3
   AND uuid = '3F2504E0-4F89-11D3-9A0C-0305E82C3301';

SELECT ROW_COUNT();
```

To save 24 bytes per record, you could use a `uuid_short BIGINT` field instead, and replace the `UUID()`s above with `UUID_SHORT()`s.

If you want to make sure no one can change the record between when you read it and update it, you either have to use `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` or `SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE` inside a `START TRANSACTION` ... `COMMIT`, which requires an `ENGINE` that supports transactions, such as InnoDB, or `LOCK TABLES READ [LOCAL]` / `UNLOCK TABLES` which work on all database engines.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I learned a few new things. However, I may not able to use it. Reason is that the products_available_tbl can have concurrent access from several terminals and multiple of them can try to block a given item. Using uuid here means that I need to try it multiple times in a loop till I get the same uuid (competing with another terminal accessing the same product). I will face the same issue while trying to commit the item as well. I think procedures are good solutions here. I learned that up and could make it work. Will post it soon.

Answer (score 0):

I found that using stored procedures is a good way to solve the problem in this scenario with multiple people accessing/modifying multiple tables here, which also need atomicity. Here are the 3 procedures to add an item, block an item and commit an item. The add_item operation doesn't really need atomicity since it always adds to the item's avail_cnt in products_available_tbl, so the add_item procedure is not really necessary.

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `add_item` //
CREATE PROCEDURE add_item(IN in_producer_id INT, IN in_item_id INT,
                                                IN in_item_cnt INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE item INT DEFAULT NULL;
    START TRANSACTION;

    INSERT INTO producer_tbl (producer_id, item_id, item_cnt)
        VALUES (in_producer_id, in_item_id, in_item_cnt);

    SELECT item_id FROM products_available_tbl 
        WHERE item_id=in_item_id INTO item FOR UPDATE;

    IF item IS NOT NULL THEN
        UPDATE products_available_tbl 
            SET avail_cnt=avail_cnt + in_item_cnt
            WHERE item_id=in_item_id;
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO products_available_tbl 
            (item_id, avail_cnt, blocked_cnt)
            VALUES (in_item_id, in_item_cnt, 0);
    END IF;

    COMMIT;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

This 'block_item' gets called when a consumer places a request for an item, but haven't committed to a buy.

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `block_item` //
CREATE PROCEDURE block_item(IN in_item_id INT, INOUT cnt INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE out_cnt INT DEFAULT cnt;
    DECLARE var_avail_cnt, var_blocked_cnt INT DEFAULT 0;
    START TRANSACTION;

    SELECT avail_cnt, blocked_cnt FROM products_available_tbl
        WHERE item_id=in_item_id INTO var_avail_cnt, var_blocked_cnt
        FOR UPDATE;

    SET out_cnt = var_avail_cnt - var_blocked_cnt;
    IF out_cnt >= cnt THEN
        SET out_cnt = cnt;
    END IF;

    UPDATE products_available_tbl
        SET blocked_cnt = var_blocked_cnt + out_cnt
        WHERE item_id = in_item_id;

    SET cnt = out_cnt;
    COMMIT;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

This 'commit_item' gets called when the customer confirms the order.

```
DELIMITER //
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `commit_item` //
CREATE PROCEDURE commit_item(IN in_item_id INT, INOUT cnt INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE out_cnt INT DEFAULT cnt;
    DECLARE var_avail_cnt, var_blocked_cnt INT DEFAULT 0;
    START TRANSACTION;

    SELECT avail_cnt, blocked_cnt FROM products_available_tbl
        WHERE item_id=in_item_id INTO var_avail_cnt, var_blocked_cnt
        FOR UPDATE;

    IF cnt > var_blocked_cnt THEN
        SET out_cnt = -1;  /* Error case: Caller supplied wrong value. */
    ELSEIF var_blocked_cnt > var_avail_cnt THEN
        SET out_cnt = -2;  /* Error case: Bug in block_item proc. */
    ELSE
        SET out_cnt = cnt;

        UPDATE products_available_tbl
            SET blocked_cnt = var_blocked_cnt - out_cnt,
                avail_cnt = var_avail_cnt - out_cnt
            WHERE item_id = in_item_id;
    END IF;

    SET cnt = out_cnt;
    COMMIT;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

These have been tested to work fine.

Side note: Since I use python, I need to use cursor.fetchone() after calling these procedures.

Comment: Ethan: I see several performance issues, as well as potential concurrency issues with the above code.

Comment: @Ross Good that you have mentioned. Can you point out, especially the concurrency issues. I will include them. (Are you indicating at the SELECT/INSERT and subsequent UPDATE calls? Probably I should need LOCKs around them?)

Comment: @RossSmithII Thanks for indicating the concurrency issues. Now, can you point out the performance issues as well. (The if/else cases in 'commit_item' are for initial debug purposes, will be removed after testing).